# How to insert data from listbox into MS Access throught VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
  Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Sammet\Documents\ChillOut.accdb")


  Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Insert into Chillfoodin (item,price,No) values (@item,@price,@No)")
  cmd.Connection = conn
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@item", OleDbType.VarChar)
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", OleDbType.Integer)
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@No", OleDbType.Integer)
  conn.Open()
  For Each sum As listitem In Me.ListBox2.Items

  Next

  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  MsgBox("Item added")
  TextBox1.Clear()
  TextBox2.Clear()
  End Sub
```

It's a billing software I am taking the entries from multiple text boxes and passing it as a string on the listbox, now I want to add the list on list box into the MS Access database into 3 different fields

Comment: Without knowing how you have formatted the ListBox2.Items is very difficult to give a precise answer. Please add a sample text of your ListBox2.Items

Answer (score 0):

You need to split text from each listbox item and then use that array of string for passing values in sql query.